# Instagram response error "you cannot like this media"

Tags: api, instagram

I have a problem.

When I use the Instagram API I get an error that says, "you cannot like this media".

When I use the Instagram application, I can like media. All ok. I am not banned by Instagram. But when I use the API then I can no longer like media. When I use a different account everything is OK.

What can I do with it? I don't want to use a different account.

Comment: Can you please post your code that triggers the error?